# How to solve "There was an error sending the request, so there was no response. " error with Azure DevOps webhooks

Tags: iis, azure-devops, webhooks

We use [Azure DevOps webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) to notify an in-house application when certain work items have changed. This has worked for over a year, but recently it has stopped working, showing the following error in the webhook history:

```
There was an error sending the request, so there was no response.  
Error(s):  
    An error occurred while sending the request.  
    The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.  
    Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

The webhook message is supposed to be received by an application running on an IIS web server.
But the request doesn't even show in the IIS logs. What could be going wrong?

### Webhook configuration

**Event**: work item updated
**Filters**: [Any]
**Action**: Post via HTTP
**URL**: [removed for security reasons]
**Basic authentication**: Yes (Username/password not listed here for obvious reasons)
**Resource details to send**: All
**Messages to send**: None
**Detailed messages to send**: None

### Possible clues

The server the in-house application runs on was recently updated from Windows Server 2012R2 to Windows Server 2019.
My guess is that this changed the supported TLS versions/cipher suits, so no matching suit can be found.
Are the cipher suits supported by webhooks documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigating it was indeed caused by a mismatch in supported cipher suits between DevOps Webhook client and the application.

I used Wireshark to inspect the traffic of the webhook request. The DevOps webhook client supports the following TLS ciphers:

- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)

None of these were enabled on the IIS server. I used a tool called "IIS Crypto" to inspect the supported ciphers on the server.
Some of them are enabled, but with a _Pxxx suffix. Google reveals this is a leftover from previous Windows versions that used this notation, but is no longer used on Windows Server 2019. This results in those ciphers not actually being enabled.
After removing the suffix the webhook works again.